# Firebase queryOrderedByChild in descending order

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase is there a way to get query in descending order using `queryOrderedByChild`. I want to get limited data without getting whole snapshot. I have use `queryEndingAtValue` and `queryLimitedToLast` together. However I want to get query in descending order using `queryOrderedByChild`. Is there a way to do this in Firebase?

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137899/how-to-get-data-from-firebase-in-descending-order-of-value/45154126#45154126) and maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589452/in-firebase-how-can-i-query-the-most-recent-10-child-nodes/36665442#36665442) as well. It's a good idea to to a little research before posting questions as your question may have already been answered (multiple times)